# Resetting user password during registration in WingTipGames

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking at the invitation flow in WingTipGames.  In [step 2 of the invitation journey](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L3376) the comment says

> The following claims exchange is executed when the user is registering a local account. It can create the user in the
>                    Azure Active Directory identity store if the user does not exist or update the password for the user in the Azure Active
>                    Directory identity store if the user does exist.

The technical profile referenced in that step is `LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail` [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L2783). It's not evident where a password reset is able to happen because if the account already exists an error is thrown.  Am I looking at this wrong, or does the comment above mean to say a password reset *could* happen if a different technical profile is used...

Truth be told, I always want to force a password reset here, and never register an account: the accounts will always be pre-created in AD through Graph.  Perhaps I do need to pull in something like the `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId` technical profile instead...

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the XML comment is incorrect.

The `LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail` technical profile doesn't appear to update the password for the account if it already exists.

For your specific scenario, the `LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail` technical profile should refer to the `AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress` and `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId` validation technical profiles.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccount-Registration-VerifiedEmail">
  ...
  <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailFromVerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  ...
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The `AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress` validation technical profile finds the account by the e-mail address that is input to the invitation journey.

The `AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId` validation technical profile updates the password for the account.